# Usuarios con grupos no recibiendo los permisos

Tags: django, permisos

He creado una serie de usuarios con diferentes permisos en una aplicación de Django. A cada usuario, se le asigna un grupo, que contiene permisos. Con esos permisos, planeo dar acceso o no a determinadas páginas web, pero por algún motivo los usuarios no tienen ningún permiso.

Este es el código que quiero que funcione:

```
@permission_required('entrada.can_add', login_url='acces_denegat')
def Entrada(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/entrada.html')
```

Esta es la parte de Admin:

Permisos de 'gestor_entrada':
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creación del usuario 'user_gestor_entrada' con el grupo asignado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El usuario 'user_gestor_entrada' tendría que tener los permisos de su grupo, pero cuando hago un *print(request.user.user_permissions.all())*, me devuelve un queryset vacío:

Cómo puedo solucionar esto

Comment: con user_permissions lo que muestra son los permisos de ese usuario especifico, en caso que tengas usuarios especiales que tiene unos permisos únicos se añaden en esa pestaña, sino debes entrar a editar un grupo, añadirle los permisos y al añadir un usuario a dicho grupo ya hereda esos permisos

Comment: Según dices, con lo que tengo tendría que funcionar mi @permission_required('entrada.can_add'), pero sólo puedo acceder a esa vista con el admin (que es un superuser)